# How Push notification syncs between different device id for a contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, mobilepush

We are in the implementation phase of mobile push notifications. I want to understand how push notifications sync between different device id's. Lets say a contact have three device id: one for iPhone, second one for iPad and third one for android. when we send out push notifications, all the three devices receives the notifications. When a contact swipes/reads the notification in iPad will that be marked as read in other devices too (iPhone and Android).

Answer (score 2):

No, swiping a notification away on 1 device will not clear it on another.